# Get data from LG KE970 mobile phone to Mac via bluetooth

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, mobile-phone

I have [LG KE970](http://www.lge.com/products/model/detail/ke970.jhtml) mobile phone and MacBook pro. Previously, I have successfully connected the two via bluetooth and I was able to get data from the phone (mostly images taken with the camera). But since then I have problems connecting the two. When I try to connect from Mac, I get pop up with error message:

```
The connection failed or closed
Would you like to attempt to reconnect or close this window?
Close Reconnect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds strange but restarting the phone fixes the problem.